# How to write function and create new field in json format?

Tags: python, json

> [{"No.":1,"source_link":"www.aa.com","brand":"Gorn","item_name":"Beautiful","category":"Red","message":"My
>   email is abcdefg@gmail.com","create_date":"13\/7\/2017
>   20:04","date":"13\/7\/2017"},{"No.":2,"source_link":"www.bb.com","brand":"Mik","item_name":"Pork","category":"White","message":"My
>   email is zxcvbg@gmail.com","create_date":"13\/7\/2017
>   20:04","date":"13\/7\/2017"}]

The text above is my data format. And I want to create new field which is Email field. Email field will be used to extract email from message field. So the output should look like this

> '[{"No.":1,"source_link":"www.aa.com","brand":"Gorn","item_name":"Beautiful","category":"Red","message":"My
>   email is
>   abcdefg@gmail.com",**"Email",abcdefg@gmail.com"**,"create_date":"13\/7\/2017
>   20:04","date":"13\/7\/2017"},{"No.":2,"source_link":"www.bb.com","brand":"Mik","item_name":"Pork","category":"White","message":"My
>   email is
>   zxcvbg@gmail.com",**"Email",zxcvbg@gmail.com"**"create_date":"13\/7\/2017
>   20:04","date":"13\/7\/2017"}]'

The below is extract email code

```
import re
line = "aghkol@hotmail.com  This is my email"
match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)
match.group(0)
```

Running this code i will get aghkol@hotmail.com.

Comment: why don't you stick to **valid `json`** and add the email field like `'email': 'aghkol@hotmail.com'` and use the python [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) parser to extract the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re    

A = [{"No.":1,"source_link":"www.aa.com","brand":"Gorn","item_name":"Beautiful","category":"Red","message":"My email is abcdefg@gmail.com","create_date":"13\\/7\\/2017 20:04","date":"13\\/7\\/2017"},{"No.":2,"source_link":"www.bb.com","brand":"Mik","item_name":"Pork","category":"White","message":"My email is zxcvbg@gmail.com","create_date":"13\\/7\\/2017 20:04","date":"13\\/7\\/2017"}]

for i in A:
    match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',i["message"] )
    i["Email"] = match.group(0)
```

**Output**:

```
[{'category': 'Red', 'date': '13\\/7\\/2017', 'No.': 1, 'create_date': '13\\/7\\/2017 20:04', 'item_name': 'Beautiful', 'source_link': 'www.aa.com', 'brand': 'Gorn', 'message': 'My email is abcdefg@gmail.com', 'Email': 'abcdefg@gmail.com'}, {'category': 'White', 'date': '13\\/7\\/2017', 'No.': 2, 'create_date': '13\\/7\\/2017 20:04', 'item_name': 'Pork', 'source_link': 'www.bb.com', 'brand': 'Mik', 'message': 'My email is zxcvbg@gmail.com', 'Email': 'zxcvbg@gmail.com'}]
```

You can use the json module to convert ti back to string if you need.
**EX:**

```
import json
print json.dumps(A)
```

Comment: My output is is slightly different after I print A. Output is [{'Email': 'zxcvbg@gmail.com',
  'No.': 1,
  'brand': 'Gorn',..........}]  Email field is the first one. Do you know how to change Email field position like your output?